# How to reset data after filtering by react

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   data: [],
       .
       .
       .
    }}}

[{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'}}]
```

I have an input which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' ) and click a button and new result should just contain the data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.

```
<div><input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} /><span onClick={this.handelSearch}>search</span></div>

handleInputChange(event) {
this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
var val =  event.target.value
}

handelSearch = () => {
let inputval = this.state.value
inputval = inputval.toLowerCase()
.split(' ')
.map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
.join(' ');
 let result = this.state.data.filter((item) => {
    let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
    let len = realname.length 
     if (len !== 0){
     if (realname.includes(inputval)){
       return true
     } else {
       return false
     }
     }
   })
  return this.setState({data : eval(result)}, () => console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.data) )
  };
```

My problem is that when the user start tying 'Korston' the result shows the information of 'Korston Hotel Moscow' , then the user types 'Lavanta'. I expect the result shows the information of 'Lavanta Hotel' but seems when ever user types a text(e.g Korston) for the next time the filtering will be done in previous result, not the default result.Does it make sense?

Comment: Although that can be done manually, but if you want to save some time and get exactly what you want, try using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query)

Comment: Thank @Abhishek Kumawat , but I would like to write custom code. I do not want to use an external component.

Comment: Great choice! But I think i got puzzled in your last line.

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly line you mean to have more explanation?

Comment: when the user clicked the ' search ' text, the  list will be contained only items containing the word typed by user. But after I update the list, I can't access default list. Makes sense?

Comment: I have replied with an answer, I would do in such a case. Just mould it for your react components, if it works for you. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your data:

```
var arr = [
  {
  'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25',
  'hotelinfo': { 
    'hotelsearch': {
      'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'
    }
},
{
  'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24',
  'hotelinfo': {
    'hotelsearch': {
      'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'
    }
},
{
  'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28',
  'hotelinfo': {
    'hotelsearch': {
      'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'
    }
}
]
```

I would do something like this:

```
var query = "korston".toLowerCase();
var resultData = [];
JSON.parse(arr).forEach((obj, i) => {
if(obj.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.includes(query)){
    resultData.push(obj);
  }
})
```

Ofcourse, "korston" will be dynamic. and the `resultData` will be set to state.

Comment: @bita  I forgot to mention realname and added extra "." between hotel and info. I assume you fixed that already while trying.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Kumawat for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could have another variable in your state for the filter expression which is equal to the input's value and updated whenever the user clicks search and do the filtering in the render function.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    filterTerm: null,
    // ...
  };
}

handleSearch= () => {
  const {value} = this.state;
  this.setState({filterTerm: value});
}

filterData = (item) => {
  const { filterTerm: term } = this.state;
  if (term === null) {
    return true;
  }
  let inputval = term.toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
    .join(' ');

  let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
  let len = realname.length
  if (len !== 0) {
    if (realname.includes(inputval)) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  return false;
}



 render() {
  const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage } = this.state;
   const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage; 
   const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage; 
   const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem); 
   const renderHotel = currentItems
   .sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total)
   .filter(this.filterData)
   .map((item, i) => {
      return <div class="item">{item.realname}</div> 
    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Kumawat, but it doesn't work. when I write 'console.log('ok')' in handelSearch = () => {'console.log('ok')} it doesn't show me 'ok' in console!

Comment: replace `handelSearch` with `handleSearch` :D

Comment: Sorry. but in render() I have got somthing like this:

Comment: render() {
 const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage } = this.state;
 const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
 const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
 const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
 const renderData= currentItems.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).map((item, i) => {
   return  <div class="item">{item.realname}</div>
 })
}

Comment: Where should I put 'const renderData = this.filterData(data, filterTerm);' in the code?

Comment: between the `sort` and `map` in the render chain `.sort().filter().map`

Comment: you want to filter all items in data by he filter criteria defined in the filterData functions, i'll update my answer

Comment: updated solution with null check, does your filterTerm get updated?

Comment: Thank you @ztadic91,It works .But there is an issue. As i can see my data will not be updated by clicking 'search'. I have a paging for the items and the number of items will be shown . When I search (e.g 'Korston') and I have just one result , either the number of paging and the number of items have not been changed.If there is just 1 result, the number of items must be '1' . In my previous code because of updating result there wasn't this problem.

Comment: then just update pagination settings... you have the items filtered from that generate the pagecounts

Comment: return (
     <div>
      <div><input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="hotelName" /><span onClick={this.handleSearch}>search</span></div>
       <div class="countHotel"><span class="dataLen">{data.length}</span></div>
       {renderHotel}
      <ul id="page-numbers">
       {renderPageNumbers}
     </ul>
   </div>
 );

Comment: renderPageNumbers is paging part and '<span class="dataLen">{data.length}</span>' is the count of items.

Comment: `renderHotel.length` is obviously the count of your filtered elements...

Comment: Yes, but renderHotel.length shows the count of items in one page.For example if a had 3 pages in paging and every page contains 50 items , the renderHotel.length is 50 not 150.

Comment: I solved this problem, but what about updating paging?

Comment: I give up, please create [Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the issue, or create a new question with that problem.